# Temperamental remote desktop... over LAN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, connection, dell-poweredge

this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but maybe somebody has experienced this before and can help... I have a feeling it's probably something very simple, but I just don't have the experience to recognise it :(

I'm currently configuring a **PowerEdge 860**. It's got **Windows Server 2008 R2** installed and seems to be working well. I've enabled **RRAS**, although it's not configured yet, and installed **SQL Server 2008**.

For some odd reason, though, **Remote Desktop for Administration** is being incredibly temperamental. Sometimes I can connect, no problem. Other times I can't connect at all. Other times I can connect, but then I lose my connection... all over LAN!

I have another computer on the same LAN that I have no problems connecting to, and even have one remotely configured that's working fine... but this machine is being awkward and I don't know why.

Does anyone have any ideas? What should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it was because the Network Policy and Access Services role was not configured. I disabled RRAS and Remote Desktop appears to be working fine again. Doh.